# Azure VM IIS unreachable from public IP / cloudapp.net domain

Tags: azure, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I just setup a Windows Server VM on my Azure space, but for some reason the IIS that is configured on it isn't available publicly...

I can open the IIS welcome page trough localhost on the server, but no trough visiting the external IP or the cloudapp.net domain.

Something to note is that I actually CAN reach the server trough MSTSC with the external IP adress...

I tried:

- Shutting off the Windows Firewall
- Opened endpoints on the non-classic management Azure system

[image: Opened endpoints on the non-classic management Azure system]

- I binded the ip's to the cloudapp host

[image: I binded the ip's to the cloudapp host]

- Checked the online Azure documentation

Comment: I tried to access `http://makeitsolid.cloudapp.net` and the browser told me that it could not query the proper DNS record. Meanwhile, your current bindings all contain "host name" check, which prevents external IP based access. So if you do want to check availability quickly, add a new binding to all "Unassigned" and port 80 with blank host name. Then you can test if `http://ENTERNAL-IP` can be accessed.

Comment: can you please display the nic configuration along with PIP?

Comment: @LexLi: the external IP is not accessible neither like I said in the question...

Comment: @CtrlDot is that what you ask: http://screencast.com/t/boiQyAQn5tSN ? I don't actually really know what to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I resolved it... Don't know if it's supposed to be that way, but be sure that in Azure your "Source port" is defined to be * and not 80, or other.

That will absolutely not work if you're not defining "*".

[Screenshot of Azure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qb57.png)

Comment: This is pretty standard with firewalls.  When your client (read: browser) makes external connections, it doesn't use port 80.  So the source needs to be *.  The destination is port 80 since that is the port the server uses.

Comment: The thing is, even when I visited the http://external_ip:80 it wouldn't work... But thanks for explaining this.

Comment: I had trouble in that I at first used the 'HTTP' template for inbound rule. It worked no problem.
Then I changed to 'advanced' view of this rule (out of curiousity) and at some point I changed the source port to 80.
I then changed back to simple/normal view again.
Things didn't work so I deleted the inbound rule and choose the HTTP template again... ...only that it was no longer working.
It seems like the advanced view had permanently updated the source to 80 for the HTTP template. And the basic view hid this info from me.